# Divergence of vector field on semi-Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold and $X$ a vector field. the divergence of $X$ is defined as

$$\text{div}X= \text{trace}(s \mapsto \nabla_sX)$$

Is it correct, that, in local coordinates, it holds that

$$\text{div}X=dx^i( \nabla_{\partial_i} X)$$?

Comment: Yes: as $\nabla X$ is an endomorphism of the fibers, its trace is independant from the choice of a basis. In a coordinate basis $(\partial_i)$, the formula for the trace is what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!